# Suppose v,u,w are distinct points on one line in $R^3$. The line need not pass through the origin. Prove that {v, u, w} is linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, solution-verification

**There is a solution to an exercise from a linear algebra textbook written below. I am new to writing proof and I would like to see if my proof is correct. Thank you.**

Suppose **v**,**u**,**w** are distinct points on one line in $ℝ^3$. The line need not pass through the origin. Prove that {**v**, **u**, **w**} is linearly dependent.

**PROOF:**

We can write **v**,**u**,**w** as a $3$ x $3$ matrix $A$=[**v**,**u**,**w**]

**v**,**u**,**w** are distinct points on one line so the columns of $A$ do not span $ℝ^3$. Therefore, the corresponding linear transformation $T(x)=Ax$ cannot be onto.

But, there is a pivot position in every row of $A$ IFF $T(x)$ is onto. Therefore we have less than 3 pivot positions and so the RREF of $A$ must have free variables.

So, the homogenous system of equations $A$**x**$=0$ must have non trivial solutions. But, the columns of $A$ are linearly independent IFF the corresponding homogenous system has only the trivial solution.

Therefor, **v**,**u**,**w** are linearly dependent.

Comment: Why don't the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb R^3$? That step needs to be justified. (And if you know that, then you're nearly done.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov If I said the columns of A do not span R3 because they span a plane would that be sufficient? For other parts of my proof, does considering the corresponding linear transformation and then homogenous system make sense?

Answer (score 1):

A straight line is given by the formula $\mathbf{r}(t)=\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}t$. So if $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}$ are on the line, \begin{align}
\mathbf{u}&=\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}t_1\\
\mathbf{v}&=\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}t_2\\
\mathbf{w}&=\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}t_3\end{align}

Clearly, $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\in Span(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b})$ which is a 2-dimensional space, hence the *three* vectors must be linearly dependent. (Theorem: Every spanning set has more/equal elements than every linearly independent set of vectors.) This can also be seen directly by eliminating $\mathbf{a}$ and $t$, \begin{align}\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}&=\mathbf{b}(t_1-t_2)\\
\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w}&=\mathbf{b}(t_2-t_3)\end{align}
$$\therefore \frac{\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}}{t_1-t_2}-\frac{\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w}}{t_2-t_3}=\mathbf{0}$$ ($t_1\ne t_2\ne t_3$)

Comment: Can we say that 2 distinct points on a line passing through the origin are LD.

Comment: @Upstart Yes of course: A line passing through the origin is generated by one vector, $t\mathbf{v}$; so any two points on it are of the type $t_1\mathbf{v}$, $t_2\mathbf{v}$; they can clearly be written one in terms of the other.